# .htaccess directives fail to redirect www to non-www URLs

Tags: htaccess, redirects, no-www

I'm trying to redirect `https://www.example.com` to `https://example.com`.

I'm running Ubuntu server 2020 lts with Apache 2, PHP 7 and Let's Encrypt SSL.

**My file structure:**

```
logs/
private/
public/
  └ index.php
.htaccess
index.php
```

**My Apache2 config file** (`/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com-le-ssl.conf`):

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
    
        <Directory /var/www/example.com/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
            Options -Indexes
            Options -Includes
            Options -ExecCGI
        </Directory>  
    
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/privkey.pem
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

(`/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.conf`):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    <Directory /var/www/example.com/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Options -Indexes
        Options -Includes
        Options -ExecCGI
    </Directory>
    
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

**My `.htaccess` file:**

```
RewriteEngine On

# First rule
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Second rule
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /public/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ $1 [L,R=301,NE]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

**cURL output:**

```
curl -I http://www.example.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 01 Apr 2021 13:42:14 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: https://www.example.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

I don't understand why the first rule doesn't redirect as expected.

The second rule works, it hides `public`. I'm in the `public` directory but `public` is invisible in `https://example.com/`.

Comment: So your *.htaccess* file and `index.php` aren't in the public directory?    I'd expect the public directory to be the document root where those files reside.

Comment: It looks like "something else" is performing the HTTP to HTTPS redirect you are seeing (as noted by Éric, you are requesting HTTP in your test). What happens if you request `https://www.example.com/`? Note that the CURL request you are making does not follow redirects, so it's quite possible the redirect in `.htaccess` would occur later. (?)

Comment: "So your _.htaccess_ file and `index.php` aren't in the public directory?" - The rewrite suggests there is probably an `index.php` file in the `/public` subdirectory as well. (The `index.php` file in the root will be ignored.)

Comment: Your first rule seems OK to me. Be aware that your cURL test is made on `http://www.example.com`. Are you sure that HTTP and HTTPS requests reach the same root directory? Are there other relevant Apache directives in your `.htaccess` file or in the host configuration file?

Comment: @MrWhite I think I understand what's going on, I'm out of work now, tomorrow I'll test your hints.

Comment: @MrWhite "something else"-> I added `Apache2 config` do i need to delete `ServerAlias www.test-domain.com`?

Comment: @Éric I added `Apache2 config`

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller `index.php` redirect to `public`, yes all files are in public directory. I tried to add `non-www rule`in the public directory -> did not work.

Comment: @MrWhite in the `public directory` is another index.php with start page.

Comment: @Mantykora7, thanks, could you also add the configuration for `<VirtualHost *:80>`?

Comment: @Éric yes wait......

Comment: @Éric added port 80 apache2 configure

Comment: @Mantykora7, OK, I did not analyse everything yet, but it seems that you have 3 to maybe 5 levels of redirect instructions, probably interfering with each other, by order of precedence: 1) Apache conf file for port 80 (only for `HTTP` requests), 2) the `.htaccess` file at the root `/`, 3) the `index.php` file at root `/`, 4) eventually  the `.htaccess` file in `/public/` and eventually 5) the `index.php` file in `/public/`.

Comment: @Éric  if  helps you https://www.cleoni.com/ :)

Comment: It doesn't look like there's any error here. (It could perhaps be optimised a bit, but that's secondary). You just aren't testing it properly. As mentioned above, the CURL command you are using does not follow redirects, so you are only seeing the result of the first redirect (in the vHost:80 container). Use `curl -I -L http://www.example.com`

Comment: @MrWhite now curl rerurns `https://www.example.com/`

Comment: That's what you said it returned to begin with? Have you tried this in a browser? Or test `curl -I https://www.example.com/` directly (as mentioned above).

Comment: @MrWhite live example `www.cleoni.com`

Comment: You don't have a valid security cert?! That's why it's not continuing (when using the `-L` flag).

Comment: I'have for cleoni.com, for www I want to redirect

Comment: You NEED a valid cert otherwise you can't redirect - a secure connection needs to be made with the server before it can redirect. You could change the redirect in vHost:80 to redirect directly to HTTPS + the canonical hostname, ie. `example.com` (although this won't work for HSTS), but this will still be a problem when a user tries to request `https://www.example.com` directly.

Comment: @MrWhite YES:))) ITS WORK!!!!!!!!! Thank you very much!!!!! If you want, write an answer and I will approve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing actually "wrong" with the config/directives you've posted, but it seems you don't have a valid SSL cert that covers the `www` subdomain so you can't redirect from `https://www.example.com/` without the user accepting the invalid cert (this is the "error") - which they should never do.

When requesting HTTPS, the browser establishes a secure connection with the server *before* any server-side scripts/redirects are even processed. If the security cert is invalid (as in this case), the user sees a warning in the browser and are unable to continue (unless the user jumps through hoops and accepts the invalid cert - which they should never do, as already mentioned). If there is no SSL cert at all then the server simply fails to connect.

So, there's nothing actually "wrong" with the config you've posted. Providing you have a valid cert installed for the www subdomain then a request for `http://www.example.com/` would be redirected to `https://www.example.com/` by the mod_rewrite directive in the `<VirtualHost *:80>` container and then your directives in `.htaccess` would redirect from `https://www.example.com/` to `https://example.com/` (canonicalising the hostname). Yes, that's two redirects, but there's nothing wrong with two redirects here. And two redirects would actually be a requirement if implementing HSTS.

When testing multiple redirects (a redirect "chain") with CURL then you need to use the `-L` flag, otherwise it does not follow the first redirect. For example:

```
curl -I -L http://www.example.com/
```

But in this case, without a valid cert installed for the www subdomain you get a warning back from CURL and further requests are stopped:

> curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'www.example.com'

---

However, you could optimise this a bit (if HSTS is not a concern) and redirect directly to the canonical hostname (ie. `example.com`) from the `<VirtualHost *:80>` container. You can also do this with a simple mod_alias `Redirect`. You don't need mod_rewrite for this.

For example, instead of the following in `<VirtualHost *:80>`:

> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
> RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
> ```

you replace this with:

```
Redirect 301 / https://example.com/
```

There's no need to check the requested host (ie. `SERVER_NAME`) anyway in the vHost container, since it can't be anything other than the two hostnames you've defined with the `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` directives. (Assuming you have a *default* vHost:80 defined earlier that catches all "invalid" requests? Either way, they will all be redirected to your canonical hostname anyway.)

With this in place, any request for HTTP (ie. `http://example.com/` or `http://www.example.com/`) will be redirected directly to `https://example.com` in a single redirect (the redirect in `.htaccess` is not required in this instance). This naturally circumvents the security cert issue for any request to HTTP only.

HOWEVER, any direct request the user makes to `https://www.example.com/` will still be subject to the SSL cert warning until a valid cert is installed.

---

*Aside:* Due to rewriting all requests to the `/public` subdirectory (which contains `index.php` - the "front-controller" I assume), the additional `/index.php` in the document root is entirely superfluous.